# How to route to different actions depending on the request method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, ruby-on-rails-3, crud

As we all know, a simple

```
resources :meetings
```

will generate 7 actions for me. Two of these are `index` and `create`. A really cool thing about these two!: The URL for both is `/meetings`, but when I GET `/meetings` I am routed to the `def index` action and when I POST `/meetings`, I am routed to the `def create` action. Nice.

Now I want to do this:

```
resources :meetings do
  member do
    get  'scores'
    post 'scores'
  end
end
```

And, you guessed it!, I want them to route to different actions in `MeetingsController`: GETting `/meetings/1/scores` will route to `def scores` and POSTing to `meetings/1/scores` will route to `def create_scores`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
resources :meetings do
  member do
    get  'scores' => :scores
    post 'scores' => :create_scores
  end
end
```

I suppose you will be also interested in having named routes:

```
resources :meetings do
  member do
    get  'scores' => :scores, :as => 'scores_of'
    post 'scores' => :create_scores, :as => 'create_scores_of'
  end
end
```

Then you get `scores_of_meeting_path` and `create_scores_of_meeting_path` helpers.

Above may be DRYed more with:

```
get :scores, :as => 'scores_of'
```

Comment: Oh, this does not work for 2.3.  What should I do in Rails 2.3.5?

Comment: Utilize `:conditions => { :method => :post }` in Rails 2.x routes. See [Route conditions](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing).

Answer (score 1):

Define the routes such as this:

```
resources :meetings do
  member do
    get 'scores', :action => "scores"
    post 'scores', :action => "post_scores"
  end
end
```

But it sounds to me like it would be much easier to create another controller to handle this, as scores to me feels like another resource entirely, even if they don't have their own model association.

Comment: I have scores resources all set up, but I need this too. There's one person that can bulk-enter scores for an entire meeting, and that's what these routes are for.

Answer (score 1):

Ha! Never underestimate the ability of asking a question well to lead you to its answer.

```
resources :meetings do
  member do
    get  'scores', :to => "meetings#scores"
    post 'scores', :to => "meetings#create_scores"
  end
end
```